# Modify `input` value

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="mydiv">
    My Div
    <ul>
       <li><input type="submit" value="first"/></li>
       <li><input type="submit" value="second (blah blah)"/></li>
       <li><input type="submit" value="third . blah blah"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I retrieve the value of the `input` and replace any '(' or '.' with a '\n'? The result would appear like:

```
second
(blah blah)
```

Comment: When do you want to do that replacement ? on submit ? when the page loads ? Also, do you replace ( with \n (as your text says) or with (\n (as your exemple does)

Comment: `input` text boxes may only have one line, AFAIK.

Comment: Please stop writing "Thank you in advance!! God Bless!!" on all your questions. There is a reason that we keep removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote this assuming you wanted to keep the separator as your exemple implied, [you can see it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/nPyds/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.mydiv input[type=submit]').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.val($this.val().replace(/(\.|\()/, '\n$1'));
  });
});
```

EDIT: @vzwick: regarding your edit no, [it shouldn't be a one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587687/should-i-cache-this-in-jquery-if-it-is-used-more-than-once), I'm caching $this on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mydiv input').each(function(i,e){
        $(e).val($(e).val().replace('(', '\n').replace('.', '\n'))
    });
});
```

Also, keep in mind, that this might/will cause problems with rendering in some browsers (i.e. WebKit doesn't resize the input).

http://jsfiddle.net/YTD9p/

Comment: Regarding your edit on my answer, I reverted it back and added a link to an answer explaining why to you. In the same level of things, both your replace calls should be combined in one.

Comment: Thanks man, I learned something today! Also, your approach is definitely the way to go. Cheers!