# how to replace all <a> hrefs within div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, href

Replace all href's within a div element by adding http://mysite.com?url= infront for example. if the html is...

```
<div class="post-body">
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com">youtube</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com">facebook</a>
</div>
```

replace each href by adding http://mysite.com?url= infront so the outcome of the html will be...

```
<div class="post-body">
<a href="http://mysite.com?url=http://www.google.com">google</a>
<a href="http://mysite.com?url=http://www.youtube.com">youtube</a>
<a href="http://mysite.com?url=http://www.facebook.com">facebook</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [**jQuery.each**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$('.post-body a').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        href = $this.attr('href');
    $this.attr('href', "http://mysite.com/?url=" + href);
})
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/c5JZt/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) method

```
$('.post-body a').attr('href', function(i, currentValue){
   return 'http://mysite.com?url=' + currentValue;
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/94Bf4/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `$.each` method: http://jsfiddle.net/bFEzt/

```
$.each($('.post-body a'),function() {
    $(this).attr('href',"http://domain.com/?url="+$(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: In this case, there is no speed difference between using `$(this)` and a cached version.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bFEzt/1/. They perform equally. It's my understanding that `$(this)` is cached automatically.

Comment: it is not cached.. it is just that the `.attr` method is much heavier that `$(this)` and the majority of the time is spent in there.. You will see the difference if you scale it a bit http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/bFEzt/3/

Comment: They are still performing equally, you failed to test the reverse order of the blocks: http://jsfiddle.net/bFEzt/4/

Comment: indeed there was an error in the fact that the second attempt was using longer strings (*already altered by the first one*)

Comment: So in reality, they are running consistently =\ I'd like to see comprehensive data on this.

Comment: i cannot comment on the speed issue in this scenario as they *appear* to perform equally.. but internal caching does not happen. You can check the actual source code at ***[github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery)***. Also have a look at ***[Should I cache $(this) in jQuery if it is used more than once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587687/should-i-cache-this-in-jquery-if-it-is-used-more-than-once)***

Comment: Either way, my original statement holds true: `In this case, there is no speed difference between using $(this) and a cached version.`

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
$.each("a",function(index, elem){
    $(elem).attr('href','http://mysite.com?url=' + $(elem).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: Update your selector as this will change all the links in the page.. The OP is asking to limit the change inside the `div.post-body` element..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line of code with `replace`:

```
$('div.post-body').html(
    $('div.post-body').html().replace(/href="/g,'href="http://mysite.com?url=') 
);
```

Comment: ***problem 1:*** multiple `div.post-body` will be replaced by the first one.  ***problem 2:*** It will replace the actual contents of the post if they contain `href="`

Comment: Meh, wasn't my first choice anyway. Just trying to think of something new. :-)