# How to replace all links inside a Div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, replace, href

I want to replace all links which are inside a specific DIV using JavaScript.
For example

```
<div class="div01">
<div class="div02">
    <a href="www.oldlink.com">
        <img src="myimage.jpg" class="imageclass">
    </a>
</div>
<a class="link02" href="www.oldlink2.com">
    <div class="div03">
        <h5>My Heading</h5>
    </div>
</a>
```

Now I want to replace www.oldlink.com and www.oldlink2.com with my one new link like www.mynewlink.com. Actually I am using WordPress and do not want to edit it using PHP. I am using a plugin Header and Footer Script to do this.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-and-footer-scripts/

Comment: When you tried to do this yourself, where did you get stuck, what went wrong? How did it go wrong? What JavaScript did you come up with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892805/how-to-replace-all-a-hrefs-within-div-element

Comment: I tried var mylink = document.getElementsByClassName('div01'); mylink.setAttribute('href', 'www.mynewlink.com'); but not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const div1 = document.querySelector('.tg-one-fourth');

div1.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => a.href = '//www.mynewlink.com');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tg-one-fourth">
    <div class="div02">
      <a href="www.oldlink.com">
        <img src="myimage.jpg" class="imageclass">
      </a>
    </div>
    <a class="link02" href="www.oldlink2.com">
      <div class="div03">
        <h5>My Heading</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am trying to use this code by class document.getElementsByClassName('div01') but it is not working.

Comment: Make sure you do like
    const div1 = document.getElementsByClassName('div01')[0];

Comment: @UsamaEjaz I don't know why it is not working  `const div1 = document.getElementsByClassName('tg-one-fourth')[0];

div1.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => a.href = '//www.mynewlink.com');`

Comment: You need to check the `div1` variable and make sure it is the `div` element you want to target. I guess you are using a different `div` because classes can be used at may places

Comment: tg-one-fourth is actually the real class of div where I am trying to apply. Please make your code to apply by class.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation however still code not working on my side, very disappointed.

Comment: This is actually real code `<div class="tg-one-fourth tg-column-1">
<div class="service-image"><a title="Shieldtox Liquid" href="http://localhost/ptc/nice-shoes/"><img src="Shieldtox-Liquid-Box.jpg" class="attachment-featured-recent-work size-featured-recent-work wp-post-image"></a></div><a class="recent_work_title" title="Shieldtox Liquid" href="http://localhost/ptc/nice-shoes/"><div class="title_box">
<h5>Shieldtox Liquid</h5></div></a></div>`
`

Comment: I want to disable all links with # link.

Comment: @IftekHar this is actually working. Please see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2ec2ma8/)